# VS code autocomplete

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

If I type tags whithout < e.g h1 vs code used to suggest h tags and automatically closes the one I choose. But since yesterday it has stopped. Though, it still closes tags automatically but I have to type < and type the tag before it automatically closes. Please help.

Comment: this happens when the linter crashes

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Files > Preferences > Settings ' then select 'HTML' and in 'Content Unformatted' click settings.json link and then paste this code in it

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"files.associations": {"*html": "html"},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Auto Complete Tag`  extension on VScode . It combines the functions of `Auto Close Tag` and `Auto Rename Tag`.